# Java show/hide object fields depending on REST call

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, jackson

Is it possible to config the Item class that depending on the REST call to show and hide specific fields?
For example I want to hide `colorId` (and show `categoryId`) from `User` class when calling `XmlController` and vice versa when calling `JsonController`.

## **Item class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Item
{
   private Long id;
   private Long categoryId;    // <-- Show field in XML REST call and hide in JSON REST call
   private Long colorId;       // <-- Show field in JSON REST call and hide in XML REST call
   private Long groupId;
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "item")
   @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "groupItems")
   private List<GroupedItem> item;
}
```

## **JSON Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
    path = "/json/",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class JsonController
{
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @RequestMapping(path = "{colorId}")
    public Item getArticles(@PathVariable("colorId") Long colorId)
    {
        return service.getByColor(colorId); // returns JSON without "categoryId"
    }
}
```

## **XML Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
    path = "/xml/",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public class XmlController
{
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @RequestMapping(path = "{categoryId}")
    public Item getArticles(@PathVariable("categoryId") Long categoryId)
    {
        return service.getByCategory(categoryId); // returns XML without "colorId"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by creating following View:

```
public class View
{
    public static class Parent
    {
    }

    public static class Json extends Parent
    {
    }

    public static class Xml extends Parent
    {
    }
}
```

With this config it is possible to set up the Class as:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonView(View.Parent.class)
public class Item
{
   private Long id;
   @JsonView(View.Xml.class)  // <-- Show field in XML REST call and hide in JSON REST call
   private Long categoryId;    
   @JsonView(View.Json.class) // <-- Show field in JSON REST call and hide in XML REST call
   private Long colorId;    
   private Long groupId;
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "item")
   @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "groupItems")
   private List<GroupedItem> item;
}
```

(Note: if you want to list `List<GroupedItem> item` in your response you need to define `@JsonView(View.Parent.class)` in `GroupedItem` as well)

Finally, if you are using Spring, the REST requests (See question) can be defined as:

```
@JsonView(View.Json.class) // or @JsonView(View.Xml.class) in other case
@RequestMapping(path = "{colorId}")
public Item getArticles(@PathVariable("colorId") Long colorId)
{
    return service.getByColor(colorId); // returns JSON without "categoryId"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using [Jackson JSON Views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) and the method `ObjectMapper#writerWithView`.

You just need to configure your `ObjectMapper` differently for both controllers and you're good to go

An example of a Jackson JSON View would be the following where we notice that `ownerName` is only accessible internally and not publically

```java
public class Item {
 
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public int id;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    public String itemName;

    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    public String ownerName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I've solved it differently, by same concept, because I'm using Spring.
Using following View I could separate the properties for each REST call: 

`
public class AcsView
{
    public static class Acs
    {
    }

    public static class Json extends Acs
    {
    }

    public static class Xml extends Acs
    {
    }
}

`

Comment: Super @Stefan, I'm glad you could solve it. Out of curiosity, how did you do that? Maybe you could answer your own question and accept it, so that everyone knows it's been answered.

Comment: Question [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66984634/11945378) :)